# Cancel editing row in ngx-datatable ang return to previous data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am running this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-ngxdatatable-enable-editing-for-row-on-button-click-7nylcj?file=src/app/app.component.ts and trying to cancel editing row by clicking cancel x button and resetting the selected row with previous data. I save the data to localstorage but I get empty data after cancel editing .Any help?

This is the code for the cancel action:

```
cancel(row, rowIndex) {
    this.isEditable[rowIndex] = !this.isEditable[rowIndex];
    // this.rows = this.data;
    this.rows = [...[]];

    this.rows.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")));

    // this.rows.forEach(row => {
    //   let testArr = [];
    //   row.nota.forEach(nota => {
    //     testArr.push(nota.test);
    //   });
    //   row.selected = testArr;
    // });
    this.rows = [...this.rows];
    // this.rows = [...this.rows];
    console.log("Row canceled: " + rowIndex);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `rows.push(...)` and passing an array to it, that does not work...

replace

```
this.rows = [...[]];
this.rows.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")));
```

with

```
this.rows = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
```

and that will get you going